# Python Selenium get two elements from same part of HTML Code

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Hi I'm trying to find those lines save the numbers 30.1 and -10.5 and click on Tony Marco. I'm triying `VaR=driver.get_element_by_xpath("//id[contains(@class, 'PointsTabL PointsSel')]//*[contains(@title,'VaR')]")` but doesn´t work. Could anybody help me please.

```
<td>
     <a id="po-s-23320221-h" href="javascript:$M('po').onPoint('s',23320221,'h',30.1)" class="PointsTabL PointsSel">
        <span class="VaR">30.1</span>
        <span class="VaM">-10.5</span>
        <span class="VaL" title="Tony Marco">Tony Marco</span>
     </a>
    </td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`//id[contains(@class, 'PointsTabL PointsSel')]//*[contains(@title,'VaR')]`would match nothing for 2 reasons:

- you are checking the `class` attribute of an `id` element (?) - instead you should use `a`
- you are checking if `VaR` is inside a `title` attribute but need to check the `class`

Fixed version:

```
//a[contains(@class, 'PointsTabL PointsSel')]//*[contains(@class,'VaR')]
```

Or, a more concise *CSS selector*:

```
VaR = driver.get_element_by_css_selector("a.PointsTabL.PointsSel .VaR")
print(VaR.text)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Thanks to you I can continue.